Using Pandas and Patches, Extract Hyperlinks From Excel (.xlsx) files, and create a DataFrame
Issue:
I am attempting to incorporate code that allows for pandas (and openpyxl or any working method you are able to provide) to properly input HYPERLINKS into a DataFrame.
However, despite seeming successful attempts in the GitHub and StackOverflow solutions (GITHUB: Feature request: read_excel to support hyperlinks split into label and hyperlink ), I cannot successfully export HYPERLINKS from Excel files (in INPUT_DIR) into a DataFrame (and ultimately, into a merged Excel file).  I don't receive any errors, it just processes it as if I didn't use the additional--intended solution--code provided by https://gist.github.com/zachschillaci27/887c272cbdda63316d9a02a770d15040.  It is possible that the solution exists in the links I provided above, but I am not sure how to implement them with my code (my code is processing multiple excel files into a merged excel file, and the solutions don't seem to incorporate this(?)).  Apologies, if my coding is too green to extrapolate a solution.
Possible root issue: I think it might have to do with the URI relative paths (i.e. ../../../) of the HYPERLINKS I use as opposed to a traditional URL (but not sure?).
The original excel files I am attempting to merge have HYPERLINKS
(e.g. =HYPERLINK("../../../data/POD-00011_2408081740.MP3","../../../data/POD-00011_2408081740.MP3")
that work--such that when you click on the cell, it will open/execute the file by going up 3 directories/folders (i.e. ../../../) and then going into "data" or "transcripts_output" directory. I am attempting to merge all the Excel files using pd.read_excel() and pd.concat() (See Method 2. HERE) to merge the Excel files into a single Excel file (with proper HYPERLINKS)
Referenced Troubleshooting:
Based on a number of Github and StackOverflow threads:
https://pastebin.com/0bBMW8fY
My Setup Environment:
os platform: Win-64; Win11
conda: 24.7.1
python: 3.10
pandas: 2.2.3
openpyxl: 3.1.5

Code:
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

from pathlib import Path

def dir_not_empty(_dir: Path) -> bool:
    return any(_dir.iterdir())


#### Following Script Used From:################################################################# 
# intended to augment pandas read_excel() to accept HYPERLINK cells/data
# https://gist.github.com/zachschillaci27/887c272cbdda63316d9a02a770d15040
def _get_link_if_exists(cell) -> str | None:
    try:
        return cell.hyperlink.target
    except AttributeError:
        return None


def extract_hyperlinks_from_xlsx(
    file_name: str, sheet_name: str, columns_to_parse: list[str], row_header: int = 1
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name)
    ws = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)[sheet_name]
    for column in columns_to_parse:
        row_offset = row_header + 1
        column_index = list(df.columns).index(column) + 1
        df[column] = [
            _get_link_if_exists(ws.cell(row=row_offset + i, column=column_index))
            for i in range(len(df[column]))
        ]
    return df
##################################################################################################

# specifying the path to csv files:
INPUT_DIR = Path("./output/xlsx_output/xlsx_run_outputs")
OUTPUT_DIR = Path("./output/xlsx_output/merged_xlsx/merged_podcast_outputs.xlsx")
 
# csv files in the path
# list of excel files we want to merge.
# pd.read_excel(file_path) reads the  
# excel data into pandas dataframe.

if dir_not_empty(INPUT_DIR):
    file_list = INPUT_DIR.iterdir()

    # Two following lines are commented out/ removed from script and replaced with 
    # code that attempts to utilize script made from
    # https://gist.github.com/zachschillaci27/887c272cbdda63316d9a02a770d15040:
    # excl_list = [pd.read_excel(file) for file in file_list]
    # print(excl_list)

    # Replacement code (see https://gist.github.com/zachschillaci27/887c272cbdda63316d9a02a770d15040)
    # meant to allow for HYPERLINKS in pd.read_excel():
    column_list = ["input_urls", "output_srt_urls", "output_json_urls", "output_vtt_urls", "output_txt_urls", "output_tsv_urls"]
    excl_list = [extract_hyperlinks_from_xlsx(file, 'Sheet1', column_list, row_header=1) for file in file_list]
    print(excl_list)

Actual Output:
[   Unnamed: 0 input_urls output_srt_urls output_json_urls  ... creation_date creation_time word_count  file_sizes
0           0       None            None             None  ...      20240808          1740         13     5036032
1           1       None            None             None  ...      20240808          1754          6      900096

[2 rows x 11 columns]]

Intended Output: Output that has corresponding appropriate HYPERLINKS instead of cells with 'None':
**APPROPRIATE HYPERLINKS to replace Nones**
=HYPERLINK("../../../data/POD-00011_2408081740.MP3", "../../../data/POD-00011_2408081740.MP3")  =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.srt", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.srt") =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.json", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.json") =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.vtt", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.vtt")    =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.txt", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.txt")    =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.tsv", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00011_2408081740.tsv")                
=HYPERLINK("../../../data/POD-00012_2408081754.MP3", "../../../data/POD-00012_2408081754.MP3")  =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.srt", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.srt")    =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.json", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.json")  =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.vtt", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.vtt")    =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.txt", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.txt")    =HYPERLINK("../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.tsv", "../../transcripts_output/POD-00012_2408081754.tsv")

Any help would be much appreciated.  If my question doesn't meet best practice, please feel free to critique and I will try to make the appropriate adjustments.

Not near a PC to provide a proper implementation, but the issue is that hyperlinks created with HYPERLINK function are not accesible via cell.hyperlink. You need to access the formula via cell.value and then extract the link, e.g. with a regex. As with proper hyperlinks, you end up with a string. You need to recreate the links when you write to a new Excel file.

Thx for the comment.  I am a python/code newbie.  Should I have said I want =HYPERLINK("../../../data/POD-00011_2408081740.MP3","../../../data/POD-00011_2408081740.MP3" to replace "None" values?  Or is that clear, and I still need to use cell.value with regex?  None of the links in my posted pastebin seem to tackle the issue this way, and searching google with your three terms with 'pandas' did not reveal anything I can try to learn from. Is there a script you can point me to, so I can try to understand?

@ouroboros1 ,  based on your instruction to "access the formula with cell.value", I am trying to implement This script, but I get "TypeError: load_workbook() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given", and line 42 and line 43 of script suggest it will not process my None values just as before.  Is this script at all pliable/applicable, or am I pursuing a script that will not help my specific use case?
